# Fade out and in iframe on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fadein

I am refreshing an iframe every 20s using the following src update method:

```
function refresh(){
    $('#1').attr('src',function(i, val){ return val; });
};

setInterval(refresh, 20*1000);
```

Is there a way to make the refresh smoother by fading the iframe out then back in? The sudden flash of nothing then somthing is really ugly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
function refresh(){
    $('#1').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', function(i, val) { 
            return val; 
        });
    }).fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Wow in 2 minutes you gave me a perfect answer! thanks edit: it wont even let me tick your answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a white div over the iframe with opacity 1.
With jquery you can change opacity from 0 to 1 with animation, update the iframe and than change opacity from 1 to 0.

Perhaps? :-)